# binary trees in algorithms

Tags: c++

Same node can repeat in binary tree
for example
1,2,3,4,1,2,3
what would happen to the repeated nodes in above example?

Answer (score 2):

It would depend on the implementation of the tree. If you wanted to preserve duplicates, you could implement it to keep a linked list of data items at each node. Many implementations simply ignore the issue and "collapse" duplicates.

Comment: means that i don't need repeat same nodes again and again?

Comment: As I said, it depends on the purpose of the tree, and how you implement it. But no, you're certainly not required to allow duplicate nodes in the tree.

Answer (score 2):

Depends upon the conditions you set. If small values are inserted to the left and larger or equal values to the right, equal numbers will end up on the right.

```
e.g.

   1
    \
     2 
      \
       3
        \
         4
         /
        1 
         \
          2
           \
            3
```

if you had 1,1,1,2,3 This would be the result

```
  1
   \
    1
     \
      1
       \
        2
         \
          3
```

Nothing will be on the left as the condition of >= places the nodes to the right.